# Drupal 7 в блоге открыть профиль автоа

Tags: drupal

подскажите - на семёрке есть стандартный модуль блога, так вот посмотреть профиль атора могут только зарегестрированные пользователи, а для не зарегестрированных ссылка на профиль закрыта, как открыть просмотр автора для всех?

Answer (score 1):

admin/people/permissions  установить чекбокс "Просмотр профилей пользователей" для анонимных пользователй.